# Pandas: delete string with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have df

```
ID     url     code
111    vk.com   1
111    twitter.com   1
222    facebook.com   1
222    vk.com    1
222    avito.ru   3
```

Desire output:

```
ID     url     code
111    vk.com   1
222    facebook.com   1
222    avito.ru     3
```

I need to delete string, if previous `code` is equal to this string and `ID` is equal to this string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `drop_duplicates()` and specify a subset of columns to use.

```
df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'code'], keep='first')
```

This will only consider the `ID` and `code` column and will keep the first occurrence, removing the other duplicates.